# How to Hide div that is not in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I asked before but it was unsuccessful, so, here I'm again.

I will have a lot of divs inside container, 3 of them can be in viewport, but one div that will be next to be shown on click is half visible, now I want to ask: do you know how can I hide the element as long as it is not 100% in viewport?

```css
.container{
 width:1000px;
 white-space:no-wrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.block-element{
 width:300px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix this using a @mediaquery

if your container is 1000px:

```
@media screen and (max-width:999px) { .element {visibility: hidden;} }
```

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but It's not what I'm looking for, I will probably have around 30 blocks loaded, this would hide them at all on resolutions below 999px.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve something like that you need to have another div wrapping all block-element divs and width of the wrapping div should be more than the div which has `overflow:hidden`.

**For Example:**

I have wrapped all `.block-element` with `.block-wrap` div and set the with of `.block-wrap` to 5000px which is bigger than `.container`

```css
.container{
 width:1000px;
 white-space:no-wrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.block-wrap{
width:5000px;
}

.block-element{
 width:300px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-wrap">
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [$( window ).width();](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

```js
$(function() {
var window_width = $( window ).width();
$('.container').width(window_width);
});
```

```css
.container{
 width:1000px;
 white-space:no-wrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.block-element{
 width:300px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. get the scroll position with `scrollLeft`
2. get position of children with `getBoundingClinetRect`
3. and do simple Math to check if element
   is 100% inside viewport.

This is not that usable as user doesn't have a hint of elements existing to the right or left. You can modify this easily to update the opacity as the element is revealed more and reaches 1 when fully in viewport.

```js
window.onscroll = window.onload = function() {
  console.log('scrolled');
  document.querySelectorAll('.block-element').forEach(setOpacity);
}

function setOpacity(e) {
  var scrollAdjust = document.querySelector('body').scrollLeft;
  var left = e.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var right = e.getBoundingClientRect().right;

  var adjustedLeft = left + scrollAdjust;
  var adjustedRight = right + scrollAdjust;

  var maxRight = document.querySelector('body').getBoundingClientRect().width;
  console.log(maxRight);

  var leftOverflow = left;
  var rightOverflow = maxRight - right;

  if (leftOverflow < 0 || rightOverflow < 0) {
    e.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    e.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  white-space: no-wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block-element {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="block-element">lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for but problem is that wont have scroll bar, on click of button i will move my timeline for the width of single element, so that will push one element outside of viewport and new one is coming in. I should make Question more specific, because i am using Json file and ajax, code is little bit confusing, so i had to ask it this way.

Comment: It is good that you isolated the concern. You can try to understand this code and do it every time you move your timeline, instead of `on scroll`. If you can add your code, again maximum isolated, I can take  look.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will add more specific code, so you can understand better.

Comment: I am trying to isolate part of the code, but its really complicated, everything  is generating from JS, after all, can you give me a hint how to trigger function every time when Margin is added on Parent, or as you said, when it moves. Scrollbar does not exist, tomorrow i will make isolated part of code that is exact as in my project. Thank you